# How to Create jwt in java

Tags: java, jwt

I'm basically creating a login feature and i want to create jwt token on server side in order to post response the jwt token to frontend as requested with email and password. In payload i want to include only a specific id which is already exist in database.How can I create jwt in a simple Way in Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JWT (JSON Web Token) library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808460/jwt-json-web-token-library-for-java)

Comment: on https://jwt.io/#libraries-io you can find a lot of libs, and usually you get examples for their usage in the docs or homepage.

Answer (score 3):

You can create it for example with [Java JWT: JSON Web Token for Java and Android](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt)

Example:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import java.security.Key;

// We need a signing key, so we'll create one just for this example. Usually
// the key would be read from your application configuration instead.
Key key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);

String jws = Jwts.builder().setSubject("Joe").signWith(key).compact();
```