# Best way to decode and store JWT's for Authentication in Android

Tags: android, json, jwt

I have a backend api I use for a web application, but I would like to use it for an android application as well. The api returns a jwt on succesful login. What are the best practices/packages for decoding jwt's on Android?

Also, on the web application, the jwt is stored in localstorage for session persistence. Would the best practice on Android be to store it inside the sqlite db for persistence? I've read through the Account Manager class on Android, but I'm not really quite sure how I would leverage that with a custom api I have built.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT (JSON Web Token) library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808460/jwt-json-web-token-library-for-java)